# Databases synchronisation with duplicated PK/FK

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-design

I am trying to design a database structure. It will be installed into a few instances of sql servers. I need to merge these databases periodically.

Problem is in `server_A` `(PK)id=222` `user=Tom`, but in `server_B` `(PK)id=222` `user=Peter`.

So, in `server_A` for `Tom`, `(FK)userid=222`, `Address=1 abc street`..., but same `(FK)userid=222` in `server_B` address table has a different meaning.

All I can think of is this cheap approach. If I have 3 servers, I seed the id in 1st server to start at `1000000001`, 2nd server at `2000000001`, 3rd at `3000000001` .... so they will not repeat themselves, that might work for a small time project? And I don't need to use a Guid/uniqueidentifier to further complicate the problem?

What is a common/correct approach to this situation?

Comment: Which database system? Most vendors offer some sort of replication between servers, so you don't have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `server_id` as a foreign key that's now part of a *compound primary key* together with the original primary key. Each server has its own id.

Comment: That will do :D simple! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the merge replication feature of SQL Server, it will handle this for you.

Comment: I have not used this feature before. Does it automatically handles the related FKs for you when it merge the repeated PKs? Seems not according to @Branko's post?

Answer (score 0):

Use GUIDs instead of ints as your primary keys. They are unique even when generated on different systems.

I'm no expert on SQL Server Merge Replication, but according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5964062/533120), it cannot resolve conflicting PKs automatically, so it's better to avoid conflicting PKs in the first place.

Comment: I wanted to avoid guid/uniqueidentifier because I heard it makes the db much slower when you have a rather large table. No first hand experience here, but if I don't choose it carefully at the start I may run into another problem dealing with performance  later on.

Comment: @Tom, the overhead might not be as large as you think (esp with newsequentialid())... http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids.html