# Merge Replication Unique Key Constraint

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge-replication

I have SQL Server Merge Replication setup on two servers and I am getting a key constraint error when the synchronization runs.  The only way I can resolve this issue is to delete the record on one of the servers and then run synchronization.

**Question:** Is there a way to configure replication or a resolver so that the publisher record wins and the subscriber record is automatically removed when it encounters a unique or primary key violation?

Sample Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblPeople](
  [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [col1] [int] NULL,
  [col2] [int] NULL,
  [col3] [int] NULL,
  [name] [varchar](52) NULL 
CONSTRAINT [UK_keys] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
  [col1] ASC,
  [col2] ASC,
  [col3] ASC
)
```

Insert on Server 1

```
INSERT into tblPeople (col1, col2, col3, name) values (1, 1, 1, 'Server 1 Insert')
```

Insert on Server 2

```
INSERT into tblPeople (col1, col2, col3, name) values (1, 1, 1, 'Server 2 Insert')
```

Trigger synchronization, which results in this conflict error and both servers having their own version of this record.

*A row insert at 'SERVER1.TestDb' could not be propagated to 'SERVER2.TestDb'. This failure can be caused by a constraint violation.  Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UK_keys'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tblPeople'. The duplicate key value is (1, 1, 1).*

Everything I read about this suggests adding a unique guid or using identity columns, which isn't a solution to this problem.  The identity ranges work great and I can even create my own rowguid, but that still doesn't solve the constraint violation where I end up needing to manually delete the records.

This person asked a similar question, but I need the unique key on top of the guid and identity.
[Automatically resolve primary key merge conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964062/automatically-resolve-primary-key-merge-conflict)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by setting **compensate_for_errors** to true on the merge article.  By default SQL Server doesn't trigger a resolver when a constraint error occurs.  You cannot change this setting through the user interface and must use t-sql to update it.

```
exec sp_changemergearticle @publication = 'PublicationName' 
, @article = 'TableName'
, @property = 'compensate_for_errors'
, @value = N'true'
, @force_invalidate_snapshot = true 
, @force_reinit_subscription = true
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.replication.mergearticle.compensateforerrors.aspx

Comment: Link is dead. Now available at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153258.aspx